# NIC bonding on Linux in redundant network topology

Tags: linux, switch, cisco-asa, arp, bonding

I want to implement NIC bonding on Linux server in redundant network topology as shown in the network diagram below.

[Network topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YooBb.png)

Both interfaces of the Linux server fa0 and fa1 would be in one bond with mode active-backup, so only one of the links will be active at the time. The bond has one IP address and one MAC visible for the switches. When the active link fails I know that the backup becomes active and sends gratuitous ARP in the network.

My confusion is how would the ASA know on which interface will send the packets for the server, also not sure how STP can help in this topology. Both ASA are configured in active-standby failover.